# Need to find messages BizTalk is trying to send out

Tags: sql-server-2008, biztalk

This is my first time working with BizTalk, so any help would be appreciated (Please forgive my lack of knowledge / ignorance on this matter. I Just started this job awhile ago and still getting my bearings on the system).

I have a biztalk server on my local box, that accepts XML from our .NET web application. BizTalk does some work, then sends that data to an oracle system.

I have an issue where BizTalk somehow got some XML that is broken and is creating 30 errors every 5 seconds in my event log. Not earth shattering but darn annoying. BizTalk keeps trying to send these messages out to a process to insert them into Oracle. This breaks because one of the values that's being inserted is too long for the oracle table.

So What I need is to find where these messages are in BizTalk and kill them (as they are test messages).

I ran a quick SQL script to search through every table in every database for the XML Value (A912478F-BB78-4e5c-A1E0-E9656B11D3AA) that's causing an error, but I cannot find it.  So I'm wondering if its binary.

Any help would be great - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open BizTalk Administrator. I am assuming BizTalk 2006/R2/2009.

Expand the top level and click on the biztalk group.

On the right hand side run a query for "All in process service instances" or in 2009 "All running service instances".

This will give you a list of everything Biztalk is doing at that point in time.

You need to find the service instance which is processing that message. Can't really help you there but it should match the name of the orchestration or send port which is doing the sending.

To make sure it's the correct instance, right click and view messages. If you can see the message which is failing then you have the correct instance.

Right click and terminate the service instance.